Wordress rest API add new param acf
I'm using WordPress v6.5 and ACF plugin. I have custom post_type and fields in that post_type.
Also with node.js i want to post data in acf fields
This is my code.

I create the function in wordpress to register acf.
function register_acf_param() {
    // Register the 'acf' parameter for posts
    register_rest_field('post', 'acf', array(
        'get_callback' => 'get_acf_meta',
        'update_callback' => 'update_acf_meta',
        'schema' => null,
    ));
}

// Callback function to get ACF meta data
function get_acf_meta($object, $field_name, $request) {
    return get_post_meta($object['id'], $field_name, true);
}

// Callback function to update ACF meta data
function update_acf_meta($value, $post, $field_name) {
    return update_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
}

// Hook into the REST API init action
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_acf_param');

2. I use /wp-json/wp/v2/custom-post-type for add new post in that type.
This is the code I use to post new Post
    const postData = {
        title: 'test',
        content: "",
        status: "publish",
        type: "custom_field",
        acf: {
            country: item.country,

        }
    };    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${wpBaseURL}/custom-post-type`, postData, {
            headers,
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating post with ACF data:", error);
        throw error;
    }

and get this error
    data: {
      code: 'rest_invalid_param',
      message: 'Invalid parameter(s): acf',
      data: [Object]
    }

Where is the mistake in my code. i just want to add the value in acf.


Thanks.
